# How to Retrieve Historical Orderbooks for Specific Stellar Market Using API?

Tags: horizon, python-sdk

I need historical orderbook data for a particular market on Stellar. While the API offers real-time orderbooks, I'm seeking a way to get past snapshots with ledger_close_time and complete orderbook for an asset pair. How can I achieve this? Any API endpoint, method, or external tool suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!